# Android custom progress dialog

Tags: android

I would like to show 5 progress bars in a Dialog.

```
<LinearLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">  

<ProgressDialog  
    android:id="@+id/progress1"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
     /> 
<ProgressDialog  
    android:id="@+id/progress2"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
      /> 
<ProgressDialog  
    android:id="@+id/progress3"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
      /> 
<ProgressDialog  
    android:id="@+id/progress4"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
      /> 
<ProgressDialog  
    android:id="@+id/progress5"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
  />
```

And java side is ...

```
private Dialog getCustomProgressDialog() {

            final Dialog d = new Dialog(LogIn.this); 
            d.setContentView(R.layout.login_progress);
            d.setTitle("Loading data...."); 

            pb1 = (ProgressBar) d.findViewById(R.id.progress1);
            //pb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            pb2 = (ProgressBar) d.findViewById(R.id.progress2);
            //pb2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            pb3 = (ProgressBar) d.findViewById(R.id.progress3);
            //pb3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            pb4 = (ProgressBar) d.findViewById(R.id.progress4);
            //pb4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            pb5 = (ProgressBar) d.findViewById(R.id.progress5);
            //pb5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return d;
        }
```

Nothing shows up. Also tried to put setProgress on it. This is a basic stuff I am trying. Later I want to set each progress bar to certain task.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

why you're using `ProgressDialog`s instead of `ProgressBar`s? 
I think the `XML` file should be like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">  

<ProgressBar  
    android:id="@+id/progress1"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
     /> 
<ProgressBar  
    android:id="@+id/progress2"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
      /> 
<ProgressBar  
    android:id="@+id/progress3"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
      /> 
<ProgressBar  
    android:id="@+id/progress4"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
      /> 
<ProgressBar  
    android:id="@+id/progress5"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
      />
</LinearLayout>
```